# Pandas linear interpolatation out of range

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I am trying to make a linear interpolation using pandas.interpolate method for out of range date and I can't find a correct method to do that.

I need to interpolate using the actual values of the index, but the method 'index' doesn't actually interpolates, but repeats the latest value for out of range data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [1, 5, 10, 25, 100]
y = [np.nan, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7, 1.5]

df = pd.DataFrame(y, index=x, columns=['data'])
df
    data
1   NaN
5   0.2
10  0.3
25  0.7
100 1.5


df.interpolate('index', limit_direction='both')
    data
1   0.2
5   0.2
10  0.3
25  0.7
100 1.5
```

The result I am expecting from a correct linear interpolation for data point 1 is 0.12.
(1-5)/(10-5)*(0.3-0.2) + 0.2 = 0.12

The 'spline' interpolation works, but I am looking for a Linear interpolation:

```
df.interpolate('spline', order=1, limit_direction='both')
    data
1   0.227479
5   0.200000
10  0.300000
25  0.700000
100 1.500000
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Scipy.interpolate

```
from scipy import interpolate

# you need to drop nan value    
f = interpolate.interp1d(df.dropna()['x'], df.dropna(['y'],fill_value="extrapolate")
xnew = np.array([1, 5, 10, 25, 100])
df['y'] = f(xnew)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Building on your answer, I realised I can use the fill_value variable in the pandas.interpolate function. So this here works fine : df.interpolate('slinear',
                               fill_value='extrapolate',
                               limit_direction='both',
                               axis=0)